# What is the easiest way to list all Component templates in a publication?

Tags: 2011, 2013

I want a list of all component templates, with some of the metadata.  What is the easiest way to accomplish that?  The Core API?

edit 1, typo.  I meant to ask about templates

edit 2, Sorry about that.  I'm working with a DD4T site.  What I'm after is a list of CT's, along with the view they have been pointed to via metadata. If possible, I thought it would be useful if I could automatically determine if 1) does every DD4T CT actually have a view in our site? and 2) are there any views that don't have a corresponding CT?  For now however, I'd be happy with a list of CT's and corresponding views.

Comment: Your title does not match the question. I've answered based on the title, but can update if the body is the real question

Comment: You question is still very unclear, You should add information like where you are going to need that list, as that will also have influence on the answer. Also "the easiest way" is not something that can easily be quantified other than by yourself. Rather than asking an opinion based question, you should make your question practical and answerable, please read the [FAQ](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) on what question you can and should not ask here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do this:

```
    private void GetTemplates(SessionAwareCoreServiceClient coreService, IdentifiableObjectData publication)
    {
        RepositoryItemsFilterData templateFilter = GetTemplateFilter(publication);
        XElement templates = coreService.GetListXml(publication.Id, templateFilter);

        foreach (XElement template in templates.Descendants())
        {

            IdentifiableObjectData t = coreService.Read(template.AttributeValueOrEmpty("ID"), null);
        }
    }

    private RepositoryItemsFilterData GetTemplateFilter(IdentifiableObjectData publication)
    {
        RepositoryItemsFilterData templateFilter = new RepositoryItemsFilterData();
        List<ItemType> types = new List<ItemType>();
        types.Add(ItemType.ComponentTemplate);
        templateFilter.Recursive = true;
        templateFilter.BaseColumns = ListBaseColumns.Extended;
        templateFilter.ItemTypes = types.ToArray();
        return templateFilter;
    }
```

It works well over slow lines and large datasets.

Comment: Thanks!    That worked for me.  I have a metadata schema linked to my CT's. How do I get to that?

Comment: Cast IdentifiableObjectData to ComponentTemplateData..

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your needs; if you just need a list, count etc, you could use the inbuilt SDL Tridion search functionality to  achieve this.

See screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: I like your non code approach :D

Comment: Well of course, you could always use the Search API to do the same thing. :-)

Comment: Out of the box functionality ;)

Comment: You could also use TOM.NET, Anguilla or Powershell.